# What does f [] = v mean in the Foldr Recursion Pattern?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fold

When using the Foldr pattern of recursion for the function product, we get:

```
product [] = 1
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
```

My question is, what does the 'product [] = 1' mean? For the sum function for instance, we have sum[] = 0? Is this some sort of limit to the answer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you understand the "foldr recursion pattern"?

Comment: "product of nothing" equals 1 is a usual mathematical convention.

Comment: What's a product of an empty list of values?

Comment: Thanks Stephane, I completely missed the logic in that!

Comment: In general, `foldLikeThing [] = mempty` and ``foldLikeThing (x:xs) = x `mappend` foldLikeThing xs``. (Cf. the definition of `foldMap` in terms of `foldr`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`product []` is the base case. It is easy to see why it exists by working through an evaluation of the function.

```
product [5, 4, 8]
5 * product [4, 8]
5 * 4 * product [8]
5 * 4 * 8 * product []
5 * 4 * 8 * 1
160
```

If the base case did not exist, product [] would not be able to evaluate to anything. 1 is the identity for multiplication, just as 0 is the identity for addition, i.e. 1 times any number is always that number, just as 0 plus any number is that number.

Answer (score 0):

For `x = product [x]` to hold, `product [] = 1` must necessarily hold, because according to your definition,

```
 product [x] = product (x:[]) = x * product []
```

But seen from a wider angle (i.e. with `xs == xs ++ []` in mind),

```
product (xs ++ ys) = product xs * product ys    -- and so,

product (xs ++ []) = product xs * product []
```

[because](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap)

```
product = foldr (*) 1 = getProduct . foldMap Product
```

and according to 1986 Richard Bird's [*An Introduction to the Theory of Lists*](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3378/PRG56.pdf), reducing (folding) with an associative operation, like multiplication, is a [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) on lists (and vice versa), i.e.

```
foldr (*) 1 (xs ++ ys)  =  foldr (*) 1 xs  *  foldr (*) 1 ys   -- and so,

foldr (*) 1 (xs ++ [])  =  foldr (*) 1 xs  *  foldr (*) 1 []
```

Mathematically speaking, numbers with `(*)` and `1` form a [*monoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). Monoids are closely involved with *folding* in Haskell:

```
foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
```

In the above, `f` is a `Foldable` type, of which *lists* (*`[]`*) are one. So it's all connected.

Comment: Do you mean `Foldable`? Lists are `Traversable`, and `Traversable` is a subclass of `Foldable`, but it doesn't seem entirely relevant.

Comment: @dfeuer yes, thanks. a thinko. It's relevant for the Bird's "folding into a monoid iss a homomorphism". then it should link up with the "monads are higher-order monoids" thingy I keep having churning in my mind...